# Search directory of multiple files for string of data

Tags: search, string

I need to search a bunch of files for a particular string of data that I have stored in HEX format.

For example, I have over 200 files, one of which contains:

```
60 55 8B EC 83 EC 48 56 57 83 CF FF
```

How can I scan multiple files that might contain the string of bytes I am looking for?

Running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: dnGrep is a useful tool as is AgentRansack.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I search files for a specified hex string?

You can use the free `Swiss File Knife` - download at [Swiss File Knife - Browse Files at SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/files/).

It runs in a Windows CMD shell, Mac OS X Terminal or Linux shell.

It has a `hexfind` command:

```
sfk hexfind [opts] -pat /pattern/ -dir anydir -file .ext1 [.ext2]

search text or binary data in text and binary files.
if multiple patterns are given then they are searched
independently (pattern1 OR pattern2).

this is a basic command to search only static data.
type sfk xhexfind to use wildcards and expressions.
```

See [Find text in binary files on the command line: free sfk hexfind for Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, Raspberry Pi](http://stahlworks.com/sfk-hexfind) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [Format-Hex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7.3) and [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlets in Powershell to find what you are looking for as Format-Hex:

> Displays a file or other input as hexadecimal.

and Select-String:

> Finds text in strings and files.

Try the following:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -File * | foreach {  
    $a= Format-Hex $_.FullName | Select-String  "60 55 8B EC 83 EC 48 56 57 83 CF FF" 
    
    if ($a.Length -gt 0) { $_.FullName}
    }
```

**Explanation:**

- `Get-ChildItem -File *`: list all files in the folder
- `| $a= Format-Hex $_.FullName | Select-String  "60 55 8B EC 83 EC 48 56 57 83 CF FF"`: the output of the previous cmdlet is piped into the next. Then, each file's content is converted to Hex format, then the content is checked against the pattern and store in a variable
- `if ($a.Length -gt 0) { $_.FullName}`: if the length of the variable is greater than 0, it means that the pattern was found, the filename is displayed.